# HttpClient request from ASP.NET app returns error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl

In my ASP.NET appication (.NET 4.8) I execute an async get request with the **HttpClient** object. If I run this code in a unit test in Visual Studio 2022 on my Windows 11 dev machine it works fine. But if run this code in the ASP.NET application (in an MVC controller) locally on the same machine, the error is:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

The request in the web app and unit test are exactly the same and use the same url (hard coded for now). I did not set any security protocol or anything in code.

Any idea why?

Comment: Run a Wireshark trace to see what the Client and Server Hello look like. There is probably a mismatched cipher. Can you share the URL (just the hostname and port number) if it's a public server? If it's your own webserver what version of Windows/Linux is it running (exact build number)

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface URL I am connecting to is https://eaccountingapi-sandbox.test.vismaonline.com/v2/

Comment: So here are the cipher results for the server https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=eaccountingapi-sandbox.test.vismaonline.com&hideResults=on You need to use IIS Crypto and compare to see if you have a matching cipher.